# SQL Server 2008 cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, cursor

I need some help with a SQL Server cursor:

```
Declare @DCursor cursor, @OldIndividualID uniqueIdentifier, 
        @NewIndividualID UniqueIdentifier, @NewUniqueColID uniqueIdentifier

Set @DCursor = Cursor For
     Select IndividualID From [MVCOmar2].[dbo].PrideMVCDriver 
     Where UniqueColID='895AE0DE-D2CF-461E-ADA9-14FB8BB59640'
        Set @NewUniqueColID=NEWID()
Open @DCursor
Fetch Next From @DCursor Into @OldIndividualID
While (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
Begin
    Set @NewIndividualID=NEWID()
    INSERT INTO [MVCOmar2].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionDiagram] ([IndividualID], [ColDiagram],
       [dateEntered]      ,[OfficerID]      ,[UniqueColID]      ,[ESDEditDiagram]) 
    SELECT @NewIndividualID,[ColDiagram]      ,[dateEntered]      ,[OfficerID]      ,
        @NewUniqueColID      ,[ESDEditDiagram] 
        FROM [MVCOmar2].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionDiagram] 
       WHERE  [IndividualID]=@OldIndividualID;

    Fetch Next From @DCursor Into @OldIndividualID
End

Close @DCursor
Deallocate @DCursor
```

I have the above code and the `Select` statement works fine, it returns 2 rows, but for some odd reason the cursor isn't working meaning that the insert statement isn't inserting anything which doesn't make sense because the individual ids SHOULD exist. That select statement returns 2 individual ID so the insert statement SHOULD work but it isn't so I am not sure what to do...

Comment: Why is this even a Cursor?  It's an order of magnitude simpler without it.

Comment: I simplified it to post on SO, my original one is more complex but the error is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that you not use a cursor for this. A simple insert based on a join will do:

```
DECLARE @NewCollisionDiagram TABLE (
   IndividualID uniqueidentifier,
   UniqueCOlID uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT MVCOmar2.dbo.PrideMVCCollisionDiagram (
   IndividualID,
   ColDiagram,
   dateEntered,
   OfficerID,
   UniqueColID,
   ESDEditDiagram
)
SELECT
   newid() NewIndividualID, //alias not needed but here for clarity
   CD.ColDiagram,
   CD.dateEntered,
   CD.OfficerID,
   newid() NewUniqueColID,
   CD.ESDEditDiagram
OUTPUT
   inserted.NewIndividualID,
   inserted.NewUniqueColID
INTO
   @NewCollisionDiagram
FROM
   MVCOmar2.dbo.PrideMVCCollisionDiagram CD
   INNER JOIN MVCOmar2.dbo.PrideMVCDriver D
      ON CD.IndividualID = D.IndividualID 
WHERE
   D.UniqueColID = '895AE0DE-D2CF-461E-ADA9-14FB8BB59640';
```

Now, if you need to use the new `NewIndividualID` and `NewUniqueColID` values, you can get them from the `@NewCollisionDiagram` table. If you MUST use row-by-row processing (you are doing something like sending email or creating a table, which absolutely requires it) then you can do it only at the last second, on the table that has the final form of the data just before it must be row-by-row processed.

To try to solve the problem you're experiencing, I suggest you adjust the last INSERT statement above to be a simple SELECT, try your process, and see if the output is what you would expect. It is likely that your implicit JOIN logic in the cursor is not quite right.

I see potential inconsistencies in how you're selecting from the same table you're inserting to, and whether the IndividualID in the Driver table exists in the CollisionDiagram table already.

Comment: I simplified it to post on SO, my original one is more complex but the error is the same. I will try your declaration and see if it makes a difference..

Comment: Your original one may be more complex, but I still *guarantee* that you can do more of it with joins and without variables than you are doing. See my update.

Comment: I tried the modifications you mentioned but it didnt work...Also, the reason that I am using Cursor is because the number of "individual" ID isnt fixed and each time the program executes this number can vary so by using a Cursor I can automatically make inserts the same amount as the number of "Individual" ID that are returned on each execution.

Comment: @Nadal, listen to me. We are SQL professionals and have solved the problem you are working with over and over with JOINS and set-based logic. Just because the number of individual IDs can vary has nothing to do with anything. You can do multi-row handling no matter how many there are. My code above will work with 100,000 rows at once, or 1. Please set aside your belief that the way you are doing it is the only way and **listen to us**. You're doing it *wrong*.

Comment: @ErikE a cursor can most certainly be a variable (though that is not my preference). While I agree with you in spirit (a cursor is certainly not necessary), I don't think the problem here has anything to do with using a cursor or not, but some misconception on the join (I suspect there are cases where an `IndividualID` in `PrideMVCDriver` does not exist in `PrideMVCCollisionDiagram`).

Comment: @ErikE I will retry your new update, my coworker suggested Cursor and then he wrote that code for me. I myself have never used Cursor or even knew they existed..

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand I didn't realize that. I will edit to make my post accurate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think you are absolutely correct with some of the records not being common or same Individual ID, I guess in that case I would need to use JOIN with the other table to make this work. A common column between those 2 tables is "UniqueColID" Any idea on how the JOIN would look?

Comment: @Nadal it would look like what Erik has written here. But if the underlying data is not what you expect, the join will return zero rows just like your cursor did.

Comment: @Nadal You need to come up with a JOIN that expresses the logic you want. If you don't know how to do that, then ask a new question. In it, you must provide **details** of each table and its relevant columns, an example set of input data and related already-in-table data, and what final result you want to see. Then we can help you.

Comment: @Nadal Thanks for having a good attitude. We truly want to help you! Link your new question, eh?

Comment: @ErikE I can write the SQL statement myself so that would be an issue. Sometimes little things confuse us the most!